# How is font size defined?

Tags: fonts, font-size

When discussing font metrics ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Font_metrics ), there are five important measurements for a font:

1. ascent
2. cap height
3. x-height
4. descent

Of these, what is used when defining the font size as generally seen in word processors, graphic applications, etc?

Comment: Probably the em-square.

Comment: I love the  `there are 5..` followed by `list of 4 items`  ...